# Design patterns in MPI: sleep root process on blocking send and proper load balancing

Tags: python, mpi, load-balancing, mpi4py

I am running an MPI code in Python using mpi4py that looks something like the following:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np
import os

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_Rank()
size = comm.Get_Size()

if rank == 0:
  res = np.zeros(2**16)
  jobs = os.listdir('/my/data/dir')
  for i in xrange(len(jobs)):
    proc = (i % (size - 1)) + 1 #lacks load balancing
    buf = load_buf_from_file(job[i])
    #root waits here at 100%
    comm.Send([buf, dtype], dest = proc) #lacks load balancing
    comm.Recv([res, dtype], source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
    save_result_to_file(res)
else:
  buf = np.zeros(2**16)
  comm.Recv([buf, dtype], source = 0)
  res = do_lots_of_work(buf)
  comm.Send([res, dtype], dest = 0)
```

I notice that the root process is always busy (CPU at 100%). I prefer the root process to sleep until the worker process is ready to receive the next message. What are some patterns in MPI programming that facilitate this behavior? Perhaps the root process should be doing work too?

Another flaw in this design is as follows... If worker proc 4 finishes before 3, then 4 must wait for 3 to finish before getting a new message from root to continue doing work. Any suggestions on how to design a root process that always tries to send the next message to an idle process? This is mostly okay for me, because the first processes to receive a message is generally the first process to complete. However, if the workload changes per message, this will not always be true.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: There's certainly ways you can improve this, but is MPI really the best match for what you're trying to do here?  In particular, why is programming with MPI better than just scripting this list of jobs with [gnu-parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)?

Comment: Certainly this task is course grained and embarrassingly parallel. I wanted to learn MPI, because I think it will be more useful down the road.

Answer (score 3):

To your first question, about cpu usage when rank 0 is in Comm.Recv.  That's an implementation issue.  MPICH (and probably many others) wait in a tight poling loop for events so as to minimize latency.

Your second question: if work units are irregular, how to balance the workload.  The answer is the non-blocking operations.  (Isend, Irecv, etc).

One possible workflow might be like this:

- rank 0 has a queue of work units
- rank 0 posts a non-blocking send to each client
- when a client wants work, it receives from the server and sends back a ready message
- the server gets the ready message and sends a work unit.
- server also issues a non-blocking receive for the eventual "i am done" message.
- when any client is done, it issues a "i'm done, give me more" message
- server sends next work unit in queue.

Comment: Does MPI use a queue to keep track of all of the non-blocking requests? Or is this something for the programmer to implement? Some of the messages I am sending are several MBs, and I prefer not to preallocate memory for every message, rather only when the message is ready to be consumed.

Comment: There is a buffer reuse rule the programmer needs to mind: a buffer that's part of a non-blocking send or receive "belongs" to MPI until the request is completed.  You would maintain the work queue, but you could only issue non-blocking operations for each client as it needed work.

Comment: I see. I prefer to use Iprobe to determine if a client is ready to send the "im done" message because it avoids having to keep track of N buffers belonging to MPI. Iprobe with blocking Send/Recv calls seem to me to satisfy the same concern with less complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something very similar to [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25838409/4794), but I can offer a couple of alternatives. I've also posted a [simplified version of my code](https://gist.github.com/donkirkby/16a89d276e46abb0a106).

First, you can make it more responsive by listening for the first response from *any* worker process. There's a special source value `MPI.ANY_SOURCE` for this purpose. Use a status object to determine which actual source the message came from.

```
# Set this to 0 for maximum responsiveness, but that will peg CPU to 100%
sleep_seconds = 0.1
if sleep_seconds > 0:
    while not comm.Iprobe(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE):
        time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

status = MPI.Status()
result = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE, status=status)
logging.info('Received %r from rank %d', result, status.Get_source())
```

I did some searching and found that [a busy wait is what you want](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/users/2010/10/14505.php) if you are not sharing your processors with other tasks. In that case, you would just set the sleep_seconds to 0 in my snippet or just directly call `recv()`. We sometimes have to share our environment, so I'm going to poll.

Jörg Bornschein's mpi4py-examples includes the [Task Pull example](https://github.com/jbornschein/mpi4py-examples/blob/master/09-task-pull.py) that distributes tasks of varying lengths across a set of workers. Replacing his call to `recv()` with my snippet above would give you a nice solution, I think.

I had an extra wrinkle that some of my workers launched multithreaded tasks, so I didn't want to oversubscribe my processors. I posted [a multithreading gist](https://gist.github.com/donkirkby/be2d583d0eb53daf82f7) that knows how many threads each task will launch, and puts aside extra workers for the extra threads. For example, if a task is going to run on four threads, the master will wait until there are four workers available on the same host, then it will pass the task to one of the workers and leave the other three idle until the task finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using one rank as the server to distribute jobs works best for load balancing:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import mpi4py

import numpy as np
import os
import time

from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
root = 0

if rank == root:
  for i in range(50):
    d = comm.recv(source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
    comm.send(i, dest = d)
  for i in range(size-1):
    d = comm.recv(source = MPI.ANY_SOURCE)
    comm.send(-1, dest = d)
    print('Closing', d)
else:
    while True:
        comm.send(rank, root)
        job = comm.recv(source = root)
        if job < 0: break

        print('Rank {} Job {}'.format(rank, job))
        time.sleep(np.random.random()%10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by adding more logic to the MPI routine before the Send from root:

```
if i > size - 1:
  #probe for response, and send next message to proc that responds first
  #sleep 1 second between probing different procs
  r = 1
  while not comm.Iprobe(source = r):
    time.sleep(1)
    r = (r % (size - 1)) + 1
  res = comm.Recv([res, dtype], source = r)
  proc = r
else:
  #initialize the sends in serial (proc 1, ..., size-1)
  proc = i + 1
```

Is there another way to do this in MPI?